# Programmable api twilio: Can browser client join multiple rooms at same time

Tags: webrtc, twilio, twilio-api

[1] Can browser client join multiple rooms at same time from same tab ?

[2] If yes, can audio/video stream shared in room be controller seperatly?
For eg: mute in one room , but unmute in other room.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is, as far as I'm aware, no limit to joining multiple rooms within Twilio Programmable Video. You can [mute and unmute audio and video tracks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide-preview/tracks#mute-one) on a track by track (and therefore room by room) basis.

Let me know if you try this and you have any problems with it.